# Bluetooth headset giving intermittent sound

Tags: audio, bluetooth, dell-inspiron

I am using a Byte bluetooth headset along with my Dell Inspiron laptop. Whenever I play any music or audio, the sound is highly intermittent.
The problem disappears for a while if I disconnect-connect my wireless or restart my system, but then reappears after a while.

I tried reinstalling the drivers, but the issue still remains.
Can anyone suggest any solutions please. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Bluetooth and Wifi operate on the same frequencies.

The long story is [here](http://www.ce-mag.com/archive/01/05/lansford.html)

The summary...

> Bluetooth and Wireless Ethernet devices operate within the 2.4 GHz band. The difference is that that Bluetooth uses frequency hopping (at 1,600 hops per second) to hop 1mhz at a time over the entire 2.4 GHz band. WiFi (B and G), on the other hand, uses direct sequence and only occupies approximately one third of the 2.4 GHz band. As a result, Bluetooth hops all over WiFi transmissions.

You have confirmed this yourself by seeing the problem go away when you stop using and/or disconnect the laptop's WiFi adapter.

There are multiple other devices that operate on the 2.4ghz spectrum... including the microwave oven that is probably in your kitchen, cordless land-lines, etc.  It could even be WiFi signal interference from your phone, if your cell phone also connects to your WiFi router.

Until significant changes are made to how Bluetooth operates, or how WiFi operates, problems like this will continue to happen between the two.

Comment: incredible..... I would never had thought about it, but... you nailed it. (Win 10, Bluedio T3 bluetooth 4.1 headset)

What is even more curious is that it's been sufficient to deactivate the wifi card, pair the bluetooth headset (tried some song and worked fine) the I turned on the wifi again and this time sound was clear and wifi was working fine....

Maybe wifi changed operating channels or something, who knows

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Sony Bluetooth headset paired with a Windows 10 workstation: sound highly intermittent. The problem ceased when disabled Bluetooth in my smartphone. It seems this device was interfering with my PC. Hope it helps someone.